# Get datalist options in IE9 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, html-datalist

This code works in all major browsers except Internet Explorer 9. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, it's probably something simple that I'm missing.

Copy this code (or [use this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/PU9BF/)) to see the problem in IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Datalist fetching in IE9</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //document.createElement('datalist');//this seems to fix it for IE6, but not for IE9
        window.onload = function() {
            alert(document.getElementById('languages').getElementsByTagName('option').length);//should alert 42
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    <input name="language" type="text" value="English" list="languages" />
    <datalist id="languages">
        <option value="Arabic" />
        <option value="Bengali" />
        <option value="Bulgarian" />
        <option value="Catalan" />
        <option value="Chinese" />
        <option value="Croatian" />
        <option value="Czech" />
        <option value="Danish" />
        <option value="Dutch" />
        <option value="English" />
        <option value="Filipino" />
        <option value="Finnish" />
        <option value="French" />
        <option value="German" />
        <option value="Greek" />
        <option value="Gujarati" />
        <option value="Hebrew" />
        <option value="Hindi" />
        <option value="Hungarian" />
        <option value="Indonesian" />
        <option value="Italian" />
        <option value="Japanese" />
        <option value="Kannada" />
        <option value="Korean" />
        <option value="Latvian" />
        <option value="Lithuanian" />
        <option value="Malay" />
        <option value="Malayalam" />
        <option value="Marathi" />
        <option value="Norwegian" />
        <option value="Oriya" />
        <option value="Persian" />
        <option value="Polish" />
        <option value="Portuguese" />
        <option value="Romanian" />
        <option value="Russian" />
        <option value="Serbian" />
        <option value="Slovak" />
        <option value="Slovenian" />
        <option value="Spanish" />
        <option value="Swedish" />
        <option value="Tamil" />
    </datalist>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like it to be as cross browser as possible in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE 9 ignores `option` elements that aren't direct children of a `select` element (or an `optgroup` within one). A simple workaround is to wrap your `option` elements in a hidden `select` element using conditional comments:

```
<datalist id="languages">
<!--[if IE 9]><select disabled style="display:none"><![endif]-->
    <option value="Arabic">
    ...
<!--[if IE 9]></select><![endif]-->
</datalist>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/T52jG/) of this approach.

**2017 Update:** It's worth noting that as of July 2017 Safari on iOS & Mac still haven't added support for `<datalist>` elements. OP asked for a solution that works will all major browsers so this probably isn't the best solution to that effect.

**More info here:** http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Comment: The nice thing about it is that it works without downgrading IE 9 users to an older, cruddier rendering engine. There are some major improvements between 8 and 9; it's not worth losing all of them just for a minor bug like this. :)

Comment: For some reason this code did not work for me. Even the jsFiddle demo did not work in IE9

Comment: @KremenaLalova Aw, that sucks—thanks for taking the time to report it, though! Would you mind saying how you're testing it so that I can try to reproduce the issue? Are you using IE 9 directly or something like IETester/changing the document mode in a later version? And are you going straight to the jsFiddle, or are you visiting just [the results frame](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Jordan/T52jG/show/)?

Comment: Straight on IE9. I first opened jsFiddle and tried testing it there but it did not work, then tried adding the code to my application and still got no luck... Then ended up doing a little bit more research and this is what ended up working for me (posted it as an answer). My IE version is: 9.0.8112.16421.

Comment: @KremenaLalova Thanks Kremena! To make sure we're talking about the same thing, do you mean that the datalist isn't autocompleting in IE, or that the options elements aren't even showing up in the DOM when you inspect the element with dev tools? Just checking as my example was only to show how to get the elements to show up in the DOM—the datalist won't actually *work* without a polyfill! :)

Comment: @JordanGray, that might be it. I was able to see the elements in the DOM, but they still did not show on the datalist in IE. Thanks for your help because you example got me a step forward in my research.

Comment: Looks like it's supported in all major browsers now: https://caniuse.com/datalist

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the solution provided did not work for me. Instead I used jQuery UI's autocomplete method and Modernizr to verify whether the browser supports it.

I ended up using this javascript code:

```
 var datalist, listAttribute, options = [];

if(!Modernizr.input.list)
{
    $('input[type="text"][list]').each(function() {
        listAttribute = $(this).attr('list');
        datalist = $('#' + listAttribute);
        if (datalist.length > 0) {
            options = [];
            datalist.find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({ label: this.innerHTML, value: this.value });
            });
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: options
            });
        }
    });
    $('datalist').remove();
}
```

For the following HTML:

```
<div id="LocationSearch" class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="locations" list="locations">
    <datalist id="locations">
        <select name="locations">
            <option value="CD455">CD455</option>
            <option value="CD455">CD455</option>
            <option value="CD455">CD455</option>               
        </select>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Used the following Microsoft post as a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn133614.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a meta element defining the compatibility view of the content to IE8, and also, enable the dummy-element creation line - it's required as well.

So, your `<head>` should now look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> <!-- IMPORTANT -->
<title>Datalist fetching in IE9</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('datalist');          // IMPORTANT AS WELL
    window.onload = function() {
        alert(document.getElementById('languages').getElementsByTagName('option').length);//should alert 42
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! It's ridiculous that every internet explorer version has it's own list of fixes and hacks.

Comment: Permanently shackling all future versions of IE to the outdated IE 8 rendering mode is a very blunt solution; given the significant improvements that IE 9 and later versions bring, I don't recommend it in general.