# Is there a tag for a dropdown menu that you can also type in?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, user-input

In html, is there a tag, that combines the text field and a dropdown? So it would be like

```
<input type="text" size="30"/>
```

+

```
<select>
  <option>Milk</option>
  <option>Coffee</option>
  <option>Tea</option>
</select>
```

So basically, you can type in the field, or click the dropdown menu (the little button on the right side of the field to show the listings) and select one of them.

I want to avoid having two fields, I just want to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few third party JavaScript plugins for this kind of thing in case datalist does not suit you. Chosen is one which will give you the functionality you ask for, but not out of the box.

This fork of the code offers it: https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen

It all comes from this pull request, which contains some useful discussion and a few pointers to alternative solutions.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JzKey/)

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 1.1</a><input type="text" name="SubOption"></input></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubOption 1.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 2.2</a><input type="text" name="SubOption"></input></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubOption 3.3</a><input type="text" id="SubOption"></input></li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

is this what you mean, it needs to be cleaned so the text field is the right size but is this what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `<datalist>` tag

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Milk">
  <option value="Coffee">
  <option value="Tea">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Follow this post's accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394512/get-datalist-options-in-ie9-with-javascript jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/PU9BF/

Comment: will it work when IE9 is rendered as: `Browser mode: IE9 Compact view, Document Mode: IE8 standards`?

Comment: Works in Browser Mode: IE9 but not in Document Mode: IE8